# If commas then get substring, else return whole string

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, substring

How would I go about extracting a SUNSTRING *IF* a `commas` exists or just returning the whole string if no `commas` was found?

For example:

```
640 => 640
310,321,450 => 310
1024,5,78, 900 => 1024
```

I was thinking of doing something like this: (suppose this string is in a table row called `author_ids` )

```
[...]
WHERE SUBSTR(a.author_ids, 0, INSTR(a.author_ids, ',')) = b.author_id
OR a.author_ids = b.author_id
[...]
```

But this is clearly not working.

Thanks.

**Additional information:**

There are about 10% of the "author_ids" that have more than one author, so `a.author_ids = b.author_id` works correctly but has `""` or `null` when there are more than one author.

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_column',',',1) FROM my_table;` Now see normalisation.

Comment: And this my dear students is the reason why everybody is talking about normalizing databases.

Comment: Has google broken again?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two methods:

```
select substring_index(val, ',', 1)
```

or

```
select val + 0
```

The first gets everything before the first comma.  The second converts the string to a number.  All characters after and including the first non-numeric character (such as ',') are ignored.

It would seem that you are storing lists of numbers in a comma-delimited string.  This is a bad idea.  You should probably consider using a junction table instead of storing *numbers* as *strings* and lists in a *string* and not a *table*.

Comment: Yeah option two is devious. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN author_ids LIKE '%,%'
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(author_ids, ',', 1)
       ELSE author_ids
       END AS author_ids
FROM yourtable
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fca0e/3/0